# How can we change Product Name for different countries in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization

I have a game to publish in Google Play Store but I need to change Product Name for each country so a user, for example, from Turkey should see it in Turkish and from France in French by default language or local settings of user's phone.

I checked unity localization which is new feature but could not find out a way.

How can I do that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you currently can't change the product name by localization in Unity.

Comment: so we can do it only on Google Play developer console

Answer (score 0):

The product name, description, tags and images change in the localization panels on the game's settings on Google Play developer console. Inside the game, you have to localize everything else (not the product name) by using the proper tool. In case you need a localization solution, I wrote a tool and open-sourced it. You can get it here: https://github.com/DFTGames/UnityLocalization and there is also a video instruction here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEOpXz7yx5Q